# Azure cosmos DB partition key design selection

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Selecting partition key is a simple but important design choice in Azure Cosmos DB. In terms of improving performance and costs (RUs). Azure cosmos DB does not allow us to change partition key. So it is very important to select right partition key.

I gone through Microsoft documents [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey)

But I still have confusion to choose partition key

Below is the item structure, I am planning to create

```html
{
   "id": "unique id like UUID", # just to keep some unique ID for item
   "file_location": "/videos/news/finance/category/sharemarket/it-sectors/semiconductors/nvidia.mp4", # This value some times contains special symbols like spaces, dollars, caps and many more 
   "createatedby": "andrew",
   "ts": "2022-01-10 16:07:25.773000",
   "directory_location": "/videos/news/finance/category/sharemarket/it-sectors/semiconductors/", 
   "metadata": [
      {
        "codec": "apple",
        "date_created": "2020-07-23 05:42:37",
        "date_modified": "2020-07-23 05:42:37",
        "format": "mp4",
        "internet_media_type": "video/mp4",
        "size": "1286011"
      }
    ],
   "version_id": "48ad8200-7231-11ec-abda-34519746721"
}
```

I am using Azure cosmos SQL API. By Default, Azure cosmos take cares of indexing all data. In above case all properties are indexed.

for reading items I use file_location property. Can I make file_location as primary key ? or anything else to consider.

Fews notes:

file_location values contains special characters  like spaces, commas, dollars and many more.

Few containers contains 150 millions entries and few containers contains just 20 millions.

my operations are

more reads, frequent writes as new videos are added, less updates in case videos changed.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to keep in mind while selecting partition keys:

- Observe the query parameters while reading data, they give you good hints to what partition key candidates are.
- You mentioned that few containers contain 150 million documents and few containers contain 20 million documents. Instead of number of documents stored in a container what matters is which containers are getting higher number of requests. If few containers are getting too many requests, that is a good indicator of poorly designed partition keys.
- Try to distribute the request load as evenly as possible among containers so that it gets distributed evenly among the physical partitions. Otherwise, you will get hot-partition issues and will workaround by increasing throughput which will cost you more $.
- Try to limit cross-partition queries as much as possible

Comment: Each storage files is mapped to documents in container, few storage as 20 Millions and few storages goes 150 millions files. can I create separate cosmos DB in this case instead of creating separate containers?

Comment: cosmos db has 3 levels - account, database and containers. an account can have multiple databases and a database can have multiple containers. Two accounts will have different connection strings. Two databases and two containers can use the same connection string however they differ by database name and container name. Normally, accounts and databases are used to organize documents in a logical way. Containers are used to keep documents of similar kind together - like order documents, customer documents etc. You can keep 20 million and 150 million in same container if they are of similar kind.

Comment: Keeping everything works to me, is there any limitation on max container size and any read query impact if it is very big container document ?

Comment: limits are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#provisioned-throughput).